# How to load an instance in class based views using form_valid

Tags: django, django-forms, django-2.2

I'm trying to build a form that automatically fills some fields in a class based create view that lets logged in users create a Job. However, I can't seem to find the correct way of doing this for fields that aren't the user (eg. request.user).

So the create view is trying to get a company_name from the logged in user, company_name field belongs to a model called Company. Each Company has an owner with a foreign key to the User model. All the reuest I've tried so far have led to a 'WSGIRequest' error.

So far I've tried to request:
company_name
user.company_name
company.company_name
company
user

I don't understand how these requests work, I have seen examples for getting the logged in users name and I'm not familiar how to do this otherwise.

Please can someone help me understand how this works and how I should be doing this?

I'm using Django 2.2 with python 3.6

Auth Models:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % self.pk


class Company(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    company_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    company_website = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    company_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
```

View

```
class JobCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Job
    form_class = JobForm
    template_name = 'jobs/job_create.html'

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.company_name = self.request.user
    form.instance.job_reference = self.request.job.pk
    return super(JobCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('jobs:job_details', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Other Model:

```
class Job(models.Model):
JOB_TYPE = (
    ('1', 'Service'),
    ('2', 'Repair'),
    ('3', 'Quotation'),
    ('4', 'Consultation'),
    ('5', 'Report'),
    ('6', 'Design'),
)

ACCOUNT_TYPE = (
    ('1', 'Existing Customer'),
    ('2', 'Charge to Account'),
    ('3', 'New Customer'),
    ('4', 'Pre-Paid/C.O.D'),
    ('5', 'Issued and Acc App'),
)

company_name = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='jobs', verbose_name="Company Name", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
job_reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
contact_person = models.CharField(max_length=50)
contact_number = models.IntegerField()
contact_person_email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
site_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
job_type = models.CharField(choices=JOB_TYPE, max_length=50, default='1')
account_type = models.CharField(choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE, max_length=50, default='1')
job_details = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
created = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.company_name)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('jobs:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: "create view is trying to get a company_name from the logged in user, company_name field belongs to a model called Company". There is no company_name field in your user model, so how do you want to access it? You can define company(-ies) foreign key field and try to access company name from related object.

Comment: The goal is to eliminate the need for the user to enter in the company name. So it just gets handled for the user. I don’t think related object in the model wouldn’t really help in this case, since it’s normally used for query sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone trying to solve a problem like this, the answer is;

Views:

```
class JobDocketCreate(CreateView):
    model = JobDocket
    form_class = JobDocketForm
    template_name = 'jobs/job_docket_create.html'

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.technician = self.request.user
    form.instance.job = Job.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['job_pk'])
    print(form.instance.job)
    print(form.instance.technician)
    context = {'job_pk':self.kwargs['job_pk']}
    return super(JobDocketCreate, self).form_valid(form)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(JobDocketCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['job_pk'] = self.kwargs['job_pk']
    return context

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('jobs:my_job_dockets')
```

Form action in View:

```
action="{% url 'jobs:create_job_docket' job_pk %}"
```